# Rust "use of moved value" error with map_err and '?' operator but not with match return

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the '?' operator and *map_err* to help flatten code that has a lot of simple matches that return on errors. The following is a code snippet to reproduce the compiler error I have been getting. I was wondering if anyone knows why *compiler_error* results in a 'use of moved value' error when *no_compiler_error* do not. They seem to have similar control flow and the function in *map_err* and *after_test* will never both be called, but there is clearly something I am missing.

```
fn main() {
    no_compiler_error_1();
    no_compiler_error_2();
    compiler_error();
}

fn no_compiler_error_1() -> Result<(), String> {
    let outer = String::from("Outer Error");
    match test() {
        Ok(()) => (),
        Err(inner) => return Err(error_test(inner, outer))
    };
    after_test(outer);
    Ok(())
}

fn no_compiler_error_2() -> Result<(), String> {
    let outer = String::from("Outer Error");
    test()?;
    after_test(outer);
    Ok(())
}

fn compiler_error() -> Result<(), String> {
    let outer = String::from("Outer Error");
    test().map_err(|inner| error_test(inner, outer))?;
    after_test(outer);
    Ok(())
}

fn test() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err(String::from("Inner Error"))
}

fn error_test(inner: String, outer: String) -> String {
    format!("{}:{}", inner, outer)
}

fn after_test(outer: String) {
    format!("{} did not happen", outer);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `outer`
  --> src\main.rs:27:16
   |
25 |     let outer = String::from("Outer Error");
   |         ----- move occurs because `outer` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
26 |     test().map_err(|inner| error_test(inner, outer))?;
   |                    -------                   ----- variable moved due to use in closure
   |                    |
   |                    value moved into closure here
27 |     after_test(outer);
   |                ^^^^^ value used here after move

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Comment: I think you've basically figured it out: the compiler cannot reason about the fact that `map_err(func)?` exits early iff `func` is called, whereas it can reason about the effect of a `return` statement.

Comment: Oh ok, my misunderstanding is more with `map_err` just being a function. It is ran regardless of if there is an `Err` or `Ok`. If there is an `Ok` the parameter `func` is not ran, but the values must be moved into `func` and `map_err` before that can be known. Thanks!

Comment: @BallpointBen it's not really clear why, though. `?` is a macro, so in theory it should be expanded into the same code before checking ownership.